# Usind JavaPos Printer How to print from pdf?

Tags: javapos

Javapos supports barcode and bitmap for image, Application creates pdf file and now we want to print pdf file using JavaPos. Printer we are using Citizen Thermal printer.
Thanks i

Comment: Some example code might help people guide you to a solution but if your print software supports barcodes and bitmaps then you may need to change your PDF to a bitmap image and print that.

Comment: Its point of sale application so converting pdf to bitmap having delay, already PDF is generated from pageable object. Is there anyway to print the PDF file directly?

Comment: Can anyone help on this please?